# Django form doesn't display

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to develop a simple Django app of a contact form and a thanks page. I'm not using Django 'admin' at all; no database, either. Django 3.2.12. I'm working on localhost using `python manage.py runserver`

I can't get the actual form to display at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/contact`; all I see is the submit button from `/contact/contactform/templates/contact.html`:

[image]

Static files load OK: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.css`

The thanks.html page loads OK: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/thanks`

**This is the directory structure:**

[image]

**/contact/contact/settings.py**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

DEBUG=True

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1'] + os.getenv('REMOTE_HOST').split(',')

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = os.getenv('EMAIL_USE_TLS')
EMAIL_HOST = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_PORT = os.getenv('EMAIL_PORT')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'contactform.apps.ContactformConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'contact.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'contact.wsgi.application'


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**/contact/contact/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

from django.urls import include
urlpatterns += [
    path('contact/', include('contactform.urls')),
]

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**/contact/contactform/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'contactform'

urlpatterns = [
    path('thanks/', views.thanks, name='thanks'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

**/contact/contactform/views.py**

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from contactform.forms import ContactForm
from contact.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_PORT, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, EMAIL_HOST

def thanks(request):
    return render(request, 'thanks.html', {})

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.cleaned_data
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = EMAIL_HOST_USER
            msg['To'] = EMAIL_HOST_USER
            msg['Subject'] = f'Personal site: {form_data["subject"]}'
            message = f'Name: {form_data["name"]}\n' \
                      f'Email address: {form_data["email_address"]}\n\n' \
                      f'{form_data["message"]}'
            msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
            with smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT) as server:
                server.ehlo()
                server.starttls()
                server.login(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
                server.sendmail(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_USER, msg.as_string())
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

**/contact/contactform/models.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

**/contact/contactform/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ContactformConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'contactform'
```

**/contact/contactform/forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': '100'}
    ))
    email_address = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': '100'}
    ))
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': '100'}
    ))
    message = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': '1000', 'rows': 8}
    ))
```

**/contact/contactform/templates/contact.html**

```
<h2>Form</h2>
    <form action="/contact/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

---

**Update 2/20/22**

This views.py now works and shows the contact form; the remaining issuse is when the form is completed, the redirect to the thanks page throws a 404.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from contactform.forms import ContactForm
from contact.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_PORT, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, EMAIL_HOST

def thanks(request):
    return render(request, 'thanks.html', {})

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.cleaned_data
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = EMAIL_HOST_USER
            msg['To'] = EMAIL_HOST_USER
            msg['Subject'] = f'Site Email'
            message = f'Name: {form_data["name"]}\n' \
                      f'Email address: {form_data["email_address"]}\n\n' \
                      f'{form_data["message"]}'
            msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
            with smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT) as server:
                server.ehlo()
                server.starttls()
                server.login(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
                server.sendmail(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_USER, msg.as_string())
            return redirect('contactform:thanks')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render(request, 'contact.html', { "form": form })
```

Error screen:

[image]

Comment: `return render(request, 'contact.html')` You aren't passing `form` in the template context.

Comment: Thanks, how would I do that?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch tell me one thing it works without giving default url that is `path('', include ("contactform.urls"))`?  or giving after this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action needs to point to

```
<form action="/contact/contact/"....
```

or better

```
<form action="{% url 'contactform:contact' %}" ...)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `form` does not display as you are not passing it into your template. You can do this instead in the `contact` view:

```
return render(request, 'contact.html', {
     'form': form
})
```

EDIT:
If you are getting `'return' outside function` error, you can do this in your `contact` view.

```
def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm() # Before if condition
```

You can remove the `else` condition.

EDIT 2:
This should be your `contact` view.

```
def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.cleaned_data
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = EMAIL_HOST_USER
            msg['To'] = EMAIL_HOST_USER
            msg['Subject'] = f'Personal site {form_data["subject"]}'
            message = f'Name: {form_data["name"]}\n' \
                  f'Email address: {form_data["email_address"]}\n\n' \
                  f'{form_data["message"]}'
            msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
            with smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT) as server:
                server.ehlo()
                server.starttls()
                server.login(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
                server.sendmail(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_USER, msg.as_string())
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contactform:contact'))

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, that goes in views.py and replaces `return render(request, 'contact.html')`?  I get `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Comment: I guess this is a problem with indentation.

Comment: Instead of using `form = ContactForm()` inside the `else` condition, you can use this statement before the `if` condition in your `contact` view.

Comment: Ok, that appears to work, but now I see "ValueError at /contact/contact/ The view contactform.views.contact didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Comment: Post a complete copy of what views.py should be

Comment: Ok, so based on the error your view didn't return anything. Did you return something when the `form` is invalid?

Comment: I see that error without completing the form; the form does not show.

Comment: Thanks, no errors, but the form still does not display.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch, your problem is very simple. You just need to replace this line of your view: `return render(request, 'contact.html')` with `return render(request, 'contact.html', { "form": form })`. That's it. This answer is correct (which is why I don't give this as my own), although the essential point can be lost in a bunch of extraneous detail - which I assume came from your subsequent complaints, which I guess are due to changing the indentation in some strange way. You just need to add that dictionary as a third argument to your `return` statement - nothing else.

Comment: In addition to Robin's note, remove that else with the `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contactform:contact'))`, as you don't want to redirect if the form is invalid, you want to show the form with errors on the contact.html template.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Ah, thanks! That works. I'm just learning Python, and this is my first attempt trying to adapt a contact form from Github. I also figured out how to hardcode the Subject line, as I don't need the user to fill out that field.

Comment: @AMG Thanks! That makes sense, as Django has form validation and missing a field now simply keeps someone on the form page.

Comment: One last glitch: the thanks.html page throws a 404. Is that an issue with needing a dictionary entry in the {} in `return render(request, 'thanks.html', {})` line in views.py?`? The 404: "Django tried these URL patterns,contact/ thanks/ [name='thanks'] contact/ contact/ [name='contact']"

Comment: @BlueDogRanch, the 404 error might just be in `return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks')`.  Try removing the slash, like `return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks')`, since that is the *name* of the path.  And you don't need an empty dictionary in your `return render(request, 'thanks.html', {})`, just `return render(request, 'thanks.html')` should be enough.  You only need the context dictionary if you plan on passing data to the template.

Comment: @raphael thanks, that makes sense, but didn't help. I also tried the path contact/thanks. Are the urls in contact/contact/urls.py possibly the problem?

Comment: Not sure @BlueDogRanch.  You can try removing the forward slash from `thanks/` in the urls.py.

Comment: I believe you want to replace the `return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks')` with `return redirect('thanks')`, be sure to import redirect with `from django.shortcuts import redirect`. Because you named that path 'thanks', you should be able to redirect to it by name regardless of what the url looks like. Under the hood the redirect is a HttpResponseRedirect, but handles the resolve and is probably what you want to start using as you get going.

Comment: @AMG thanks, no luck with those two changes. This is a mystery :(

Comment: @BlueDogRanch, maybe the answer is in the answer already given by @onapte.  Try `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contactform:thanks'))`, or building on the comment by @AMG,  `return redirect('contactform:thanks')`.

Comment: if using @raphael's suggestion, you may need to update your url path in `/contact/contact/urls.py` from `path('contact/', include('contactform.urls')),` to `path('contact/', include('contactform.urls', namespace='contactform')),` See [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#id5)

Comment: Mystery, nothing works. Thanks for everyone's help, but I'm quitting for the night :( I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch can you update your answer with new views.py and additionally, a screenshot of your current template.

Comment: @onapte thanks for your help; I added an updated views.py to the bottom on my question. /contact/contactform/templates/contact.html hasn't changed.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I guess using `reverse('contactform:thanks')` instead of `redirect('contactform:thanks')`  should work. Make sure to import `reverse` from `django.urls`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work

Comment: @BlueDogRanch As a fix around, I would suggest you to use `return render(request, 'thanks.html', {})`. This is not the correct way, but temporarily you can use this. And is there any error when you use `return reverse('contactform:thanks')`?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch, clear your browser's cookies.  I just reproduced your error on my end with my own project.

Comment: Cleared cookies and cache, still no luck. I added the 404 screen to the bottom of my question that appears when using the views.py I updated yesterday; maybe the 404 details gives some clues. Trying `reverse('contactform:thanks')` and `import reverse...` didn't work.

Comment: I don't have an answer, @BlueDogRanch.  Just a couple of suggestions of where to look.  First, in screenshot, it's looking for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/` *not* the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/thanks/` *or* the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/contactform/`.  Second, there is a space between `contact/` and either `thanks/` *or `contact/`, which shouldn't be there (and don't see here where it came from).  Last suggestion, stick with `redirect`, remove all forward slashes from the urls.py (except for the admin), and the redirects, and clear all browser history, stop the server and retry.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I appreciate the help; Razenstein had the simplest answer, though answers in this thread helped fix other bugs.

Answer (score 1):

After, you updated the project on **Update 2/20/22**

You forgot to register the default `path` for `contactform` app in `url_patterns` list.

your **/contact/contact/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

from django.urls import include
urlpatterns += [
    path('contact/', include('contactform.urls')),
]

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

It should be :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('contactform.urls'))
]

from django.urls import include
urlpatterns += [
    path('contact/', include('contactform.urls')),
]

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Try this and tell if it works?

you have to add  `path('', include('contactform.urls'))` in `urls.py` of main project.

As, if we remove all things by testing it very simply and updating `views.py` through following code:

**/contact/contactform/views.py**

```
from contactform.forms import ContactForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.cleaned_data

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})


def thanks(req):
    return render(req, 'thanks.html')
```

The above code worked very efficiently.So, i drew the conclusion that it will work.

Try it.

And one thing, i would like to focus on is, always use the following pattern while making templates file.

**Appname/templates/Appname/anyfile.html**

Like in your case:

**contactform/templates/contactform/contact.html**

You have missed the third step after `templates`, well its not necessary, but if you do it is a good practice.

You have forgot `/` too while redirecting in your `views.py`.

It should be `return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')`
rather than `return HttpResponseRedirect ('/thanks')`

Also, remove the `action` attribute of form so that it can redirect through HttpResponseRedirect () method.

Comment: Thanks! This works. I do see a warning in debug "WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'contactform' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace" and I don't know how serious that is.

Comment: And what is the difference between the two `urlpatterns =` blocks in  /contact/contact/urls.py ?

Comment: It includes the urls of `contactform` by default, i.e, any path which you type in url if it is blank then its next `urls` will be decided through that particular `app`, like in your case it is `contactform`. But, what is the issue you are facing right now?

Comment: I get the error warning in debug "WARNINGS: ?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'contactform' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace"  Razenstein's answer works with the original views.

Answer (score -2):

Your Django form doesn't display because you are not passing the form to your html template. you have to pass it.

```
return render(request, 'contact.html','form':form)
```

try this and it should be work:

```
def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.cleaned_data
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = EMAIL_HOST_USER
            msg['To'] = EMAIL_HOST_USER
            msg['Subject'] = f'Personal site {form_data["subject"]}'
            message = f'Name: {form_data["name"]}\n' \
                  f'Email address: {form_data["email_address"]}\n\n' \
                  f'{form_data["message"]}'
            msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
            with smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT) as server:
                server.ehlo()
                server.starttls()
                server.login(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
                server.sendmail(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_USER, msg.as_string())
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('contactform:contact')

    return render(request, 'contact.html','form':form)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
        model = your_model_name
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: "ValueError at /contact/contact/ The view contactform.views.contact didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Comment: I edited my questing.  try now. you was using `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contactform:contact'))` but it should be `return HttpResponseRedirect('contactform:contact')`

Comment: Still doesn't show the form

Comment: are you getting any error ? can you access the contact page now?

Comment: No errors; I only see the "Send" button, not the form fields.

Comment: try this `{{ form }}` instead of `{{ form.as_p }}`.

Comment: Doesn't work....

Comment: let try with `forms.ModelForm` instead of `forms.Form`

Comment: You might be doing mistake any mistake in your forms.py.

Comment: I updated my my question. Try Model forms and let me know. Hope this time your problem will be solved :).

Comment: I don't understand the changes to forms.py; post a complete copy of the file. What goes in models.py?